# Загрузка музыки в вк

Tags: c++, qt, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Пытаюсь загрузить аудиофайл через api вк (с++, qt). Загрузка на сайт проходит нормально, но при попытке вызвать метод api.vk.com/method/audio.save приходит "invalid hash".
Post-запрос такой:(токен намеренно изменен):
[https://api.vk.com/method/audio.save.xml?access_token=f60160adc63fce978df49689686d5194dd3а6e6f1e7d79ee83cfbdaba28c961ffa51428894497b63c7472&v=5.73&audio=%7B%22audio%22%3A%2280ef0137e7%22%2C%22time%22%3A116%2C%22artist%22%3A%22%22%2C%22title%22%3A%22%22%2C%22genre%22%3A0%2C%22album%22%3A%22%22%2C%22bitrate%22%3A40%2C%22bitrate_mode%22%3A%22cbr%22%2C%22md5%22%3A%22dad5bba12c1f7b7191aa5af0096e0403%22%2C%22md5_data_size%22%3A%22582661%22%2C%22kad%22%3A%220e0002ababffabda800a7415adfdfcb4%22%2C%22orig_info%22%3A%7B%22uid%22%3A23723010%2C%22tag%22%3A%226f627e996d%22%2C%22srv%22%3A813437%7D%7D&server=813535&hash=d6dbdee9283fa0ba87e470f8b43df890](https://api.vk.com/method/audio.save.xml?access_token=f60160adc63fce978df49689686d5194dd3%D0%B06e6f1e7d79ee83cfbdaba28c961ffa51428894497b63c7472&v=5.73&audio=%7B%22audio%22%3A%2280ef0137e7%22%2C%22time%22%3A116%2C%22artist%22%3A%22%22%2C%22title%22%3A%22%22%2C%22genre%22%3A0%2C%22album%22%3A%22%22%2C%22bitrate%22%3A40%2C%22bitrate_mode%22%3A%22cbr%22%2C%22md5%22%3A%22dad5bba12c1f7b7191aa5af0096e0403%22%2C%22md5_data_size%22%3A%22582661%22%2C%22kad%22%3A%220e0002ababffabda800a7415adfdfcb4%22%2C%22orig_info%22%3A%7B%22uid%22%3A23723010%2C%22tag%22%3A%226f627e996d%22%2C%22srv%22%3A813437%7D%7D&server=813535&hash=d6dbdee9283fa0ba87e470f8b43df890)
В чем причина ошибки? Когда эти же поля тестирую на странице https://vk.com/dev/audio.save в форме ввода полей, все корректно работает.

Comment: Коли хеш идет последним, то будет недурно проверить, не посылаете ли вы случаем в хвосте еще что-то.

Comment: Думаю, дело не в хэше: создал хранимую процедуру, когда передаю хэш через аргументы, все работает. Когда в аргументах передаю audio, а остальные параметры - зашиты - ошибка воспроизводится

Answer (score 2):

[Audio api](https://vk.com/dev/audio_api) отключили для сторонних приложений, исключения составляют лишь особые приложения, имеющие ценность для своей аудитории. Примечательно, что описание методов *Audio API* полностью скрыто из документации. Вполне возможно, что для сторонних приложений его отключили полностью.

Comment: Нет, _**загрузку**_ аудиозаписей вконтакте не отключил и даже дока по загрузке аудиозаписей на сервера вк находится в открытом доступе: [ccылка](https://vk.com/dev/upload_files_2?f=8.%20%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9)
вк постарался затруднить именно скачку аудио

Comment: "Существующие методы секции audio будут недоступны для вызова, кроме методов для загрузки аудиофайлов."

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего у тебя проблемы с доступом к аудиозаписям. Думаю что загрузку файлов блокирует сам сайт, тк у ВК есть защита от ботов.

Comment: Нет, доступ к аудиозаписям есть. Загрузка проходит успешно, иначе бы мне не выдавались параметры для подтверждения аудиозаписи.  Файл соответствует загружаемым требованиям.